# Unable to access all files in iOS using cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

Im using
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory,function(root){},err);

But I'm unable to get all the files. Camera files are also not accessible.
How to resolve ?

Comment: I used all types of cordova.file.* but nothing worked.

Comment: ios apps are sandboxed, you can only get your app files, not the device files. So you probably don't have any files on the dataDirectory

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by 'access to all files' ? do you want to pick images ?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, we cannot access the all files using cordova file plugin whereas Android has support for accessing files form externalRootDirectory. Specific to iOS its better to use imagePicker, audioPicker plugins to access camera files.